# Put multiple values in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, initialization

I have a issue that i cant solve.

Here is the code

```
 sik input = new sik();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        {
            input.skId = securitiesArray[i].skId;
            input.country = securitiesArray[i].country;

        }
   sik[] inputs = new sik[]
            {
                input
            };
```

Now i know this will only put 1 value in the sik[] list.

How can i put all the 5 values in this list.

Thanks

Note: i cannot initialize ski[] first. This has to be done in that order.

Comment: What is the type of `securitiesArray`? Is it `sik[]`?

Comment: I changed your title. `sik[]` is an array. An `ArrayList` is an untyped dynamic list from .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any reason that it has to be an array?

```
List<sik> input = new List<sik>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{
    var newInput = new sik();        
    newInput.skId = securitiesArray[i].skId;
    newInput.country = securitiesArray[i].country;
    input.Add(newInput);
}
```

The reason that the List is useful is that it can dynamically grow with you, so you have no need to worry about how many instances you may need to add.

MSDN Documentation for List and all of it's glorious methods
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
    sik[] inputs = new sik[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        sik input = new sik();
        input.skId = securitiesArray[i].skId;
        input.country = securitiesArray[i].country;
        inputs[i] = input;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to do this.

```
sik[] inputs = securitiesArray.Select(item => 
    new sik() 
    { 
        skId = item.skId, 
        country = item.country 
    }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have variable size array, instead you can use List.

```
    List<sik> siks = new List<sik>();
    sik input = new sik();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        input.skId = securitiesArray[i].skId;
        input.country = securitiesArray[i].country;

        siks.Add(input);
    }
```

If you want array yet, use `sik[] inputs = skis.ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here the Linq approach:

```
sik[] inputs = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
    .Select(i => new sik{ kId = securitiesArray[i].skId, country = securitiesArray[i].country})
    .ToArray();
```

If `securitiesArray` is of type `sik`(the properties suggest), you can select directly from it:

```
sik[] inputs = securitiesArray.Take(5).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this,

```
List<sik> input=new List<sik>();
for(int i=0;i<securitiesArray.Length;i++)
{
   input.Add(new{skId=securitiesArray[i].skid,country=securitiesArray[i].country});
}
```